# f.submit doesn't work upon return of the form after an error in input has been submitted Rails 5.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have worked on this issue for over a week and cannot resolve it.  I'd really appreciate any further suggestions.

I have a simple log-in procedure that was working prior to upgrade to Rails 5.1, but now:

a) The f.submit button works correctly upon first entry to the login form, the data in the login form is entered either correctly or incorrectly (i.e. logs the user in if correct; displays an error on the login form if entry is not correct)

b) The f.submit button does nothing (there is no system log activity) upon entering data into the login form after it has returned with an error message due to incorrect data entry - whether my input is correct or incorrect on second entry.

I have read every suggestion I have found and nothing works.  I have:

1. Checked that f.submit is within the form
2. Checked that the params in the controller match the table schema
3. Checked for missing endings in the form, i.e. ' " ',/div, %>, comment endings....
4. Checked that when it does work the method is "post" and when new the method is "get"
5. Added "data: { disable_with: false }" in the button request statement upon seeing data-disable-with="login"  when viewing the form's source.   This does remove "data-disable-with="login", but the f.submit button still does not work.
6. Tried putting turbolinks-false:false in the request.

Player model (User):

```
Class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token
before_save   :downcase_email

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email_address, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255}, 
                     format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

has_secure_password

validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

# Returns the hash digest of the given string.

validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15}
validates :age, presence: true  
validates :gender, presence: true
validates :level, presence: true  
validates :country_id, presence: true

belongs_to :country
has_many :player_bonuses

accepts_nested_attributes_for :player_bonuses
```

Session Controller - def CREATE:

```
def create
   player = Player.find_by(email_address: params[:session][:email_address].downcase)
  @player = player
  if player && player.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

  #Log the player
  log_in player
  params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(player) : forget(player)
  increment_points(player)
  case @direct_flag 
     when 1
         redirect_to return_bonus_path(:player_id => player.id)
     when 2
         redirect_to lobby_path(:player_id => player.id)
     else
         session[:last_page] = 
         redirect_to root_url
     end            
  else
    # Create an error message.
     flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

Session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  # Logs in the given player.
  def log_in(player)
    session[:player_id] = player.id
  end

  # Remembers a player in a persistent session.
  def remember(player)
     player.remember
     cookies.permanent.signed[:player_id] = player.id
     cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = player.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the player corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_player
     if (player_id = session[:player_id])
       @current_player ||= Player.find_by(id: player_id)
     elsif (player_id = cookies.signed[:player_id])
       player = Player.find_by(id: player_id)
       log_in player
       @current_player = player
     end
  end

  # Returns true if the player is logged in, false otherwise.

  def logged_in?
    !current_player.nil?
  end

 # gets a persistent session.
 def forget(player)
   player.forget
   cookies.delete(:player_id)
   cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 end

 def log_out
   forget(current_player)
   session.delete(:player_id)
   @current_player = nil
 end

 # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
 def redirect_back_or(default)
   redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
   session.delete(:forwarding_url)
 end

 # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
 def store_location
   session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
 end

end
```

"New" form:

```
<%= render 'layouts/loginheader' %>
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
       <h3>Log in</h3>
       <div id="danger">
          <%= flash[:error]%>
       </div>
       <div id="success">
         <%= flash[:notice]%>
       </div>

       <br><%= f.label :email_address %>
       <%= f.email_field :email_address, class: 'form-control' %>

       <%= f.label :password %>
       <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

       <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "checkbox inline" do %><br><br>
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
          <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
       <% end %>

       <div class="actions">
          <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
          <%= f.submit 'login',data: { disable_with: false },class: "btn btn-warning" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <%= link_to 'Register', register_path, class: "btn  btn-warning" %>
       </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Debugger output at time of failure:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters

parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

utf8: "✓"
```

authenticity_token:pLZrJe9UtOs67Y5bBB7Ag8DF8KIR85zy4j9ti4FwnrMi8DTA2o4Uf01VOKFSPAr6VnBMts+OUfFZaX2cKftUTA==

```
  session: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters

  parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

    email_address: xxxxxxx@bigpond.net.au

    password: Luc

    remember_me: '0'

  permitted: false

commit: login

controller: sessions

action: create

permitted: false
```

Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only to close the question.   The login screen is working correctly all of sudden.   I have made unrelated changes to the application:  deleting unneeded javascripts, css files and moving non-application specific ones to the public folder.  I have also continued developing the application and another addition/change may have affected this.   Although it would be great to know what change has affected this issue, I am still very happy to have it working.

Thank you to anyone who gave it some thought.